# Error when activating Anaconda in Git Bash

Tags: anaconda, git-bash

I'm trying to activate an Anaconda environment from a Git Bash in Win10. Strangely it was working at first, I managed to activated it, launch a jupyter notebook and run bash commands in the notebook (my goal).

However, now I'm getting this error below:

```
$ source /c/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Scripts/activate
bash: eval: line 57: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: eval: line 57: `PS1=''(Anaconda3)'\[\033]0;$TITLEPREFIX:$PWD\007\]\n\[\033[32m\]\u@\h \[\033[35m\]$MSYSTEM \[\033[33m\]\w\[\033[36m\]`__git_ps1`\[\033[0m\]\n$ ''
```

The contents of my `activate` script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
_CONDA_ROOT="C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3"
\. "$_CONDA_ROOT/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" || return $?
conda activate "$@"
```

And the function I think is relevant from `conda.sh`:

```
__conda_activate() {
    if [ -n "${CONDA_PS1_BACKUP:+x}" ]; then
        # Handle transition from shell activated with conda <= 4.3 to a subsequent activation
        # after conda updated to >= 4.4. See issue #6173.
        PS1="$CONDA_PS1_BACKUP"
        \unset CONDA_PS1_BACKUP
    fi

    \local cmd="$1"
    shift
    \local ask_conda
    OLDPATH="${PATH}"
    __add_sys_prefix_to_path
    # The below is line 57 in the original file:
    ask_conda="$(PS1="$PS1" "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA shell.posix "$cmd" "$@")" || \return $?
    PATH="${OLDPATH}"
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __conda_hashr
}
```

Any help pointing towards how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Found what was causing the error. In `~/.condarc` file, this line seems to conflict with activate from bash:

`env_prompt: "'({name})'"`

Just commented it out and it activated nicely.

For info, the purpose of that line is to show only the name of the directory when activating environemnts with the `--prefix <path>` option.